# Выбор значения select значением из БД

Tags: html, php, mysql

Привет.
Есть форма редактирования некой БД.
В форме есть select.
Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке формы уже были отмечены те select, radiobuttom, checkbox, значения которых уже есть в БД?
Просто сейчас при сохранении все перезаписывается или приходится всю форму заново заполнять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала делаешь выборку из базы с помощью запроса SQL и записываешь нужные тебе значения в разные переменные. Например, тебе нужно достать из базы имя человека и вставить в "текстбокс". Пишеш запрос с использованием селекта и запихиваешь результат в переменную `name;`.
Потом эту переменную просто выводишь в текстбокс таким способом:

```
 [php] <? 
    ~ 
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$page.'"> 
    <textarea>'.$text.'</textarea>'; 
    ~ 
    ?>[/php]
```

В твоем случае это будет:

```
 [php] <? 
            ~ 
            echo '<input type="text" value="'.$page.'"> 
            <textarea>'.$name.'</textarea>'; 
            ~ 
            ?>[/php]
```

И так далее, только менять нужно имена переменных и названия твоих полей, текстбоксов и/или чекбоксов.

И еще интересно, может, поможет: http://www.simplemachines.ru/index.php?topic=4723.0

Comment: Мне нужно что то типа selected="selected". А как сделать не пойму.

Comment: Пусть вытягиваем из БД данные и записываем их в переменную $a.
Получаем:
<select name="myselect">
<option value="1" <?php if ($a==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Chicago</option>
<option value="2" <?php if ($a==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Moscow</option>
<option value="3" <?php if ($a==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>London</option>
<option value="4" <?php if ($a==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>New York</option>
</select